# How to set multiple task per hour?

Tags: javascript

I need to set multiple tasks per hour, but can't figure out how to do it.
This is my code so far:

`

```
let daySchedule = [
  "08:00", 
  "09:00", 
  "10:00", 
  "11:00", 
  "12:00", 
  "13:00", 
  "14:00", 
  "15:00", 
  "16:00", 
  "17:00", 
  "18:00", 
  "19:00",
  "20:00"
];

let tasks = [1, 2, 3]; 

let taskDescriptions = [
  "Checking vegetables",
  "Baking bread",
  "Cleaning",
  "Free hour"
];

let temp= 0;

while(temp!=daySchedule.length){
     temp%tasks[0]===1 
     ? (console.log(daySchedule[temp] + " " + taskDescriptions[0])) 
     : (console.log(daySchedule[temp] + " " + taskDescriptions[3]))
     temp++;
}
```

`

The outcome should be:
08:00 - Checking vegetables
09:00 - Checking vegetables, Baking bread
10:00 - Checking vegetables, Baking bread, Cleaning

I used a while loop and modulo for tasks[0], but I can't figure out how to display the other tasks per hour?

Comment: Please explain logic of relation between `daySchedule`, `tasks` and `taskDescription`. What output you expect for `20:00` and why?

Comment: Where is the connection between the hour and the task list?

Comment: @Justinas: tasks is array containing hours, and taskDescription is array containing the tasks which has to be done every x hours. 

So tasks[3, 2, 6] means that taskDescription[0] should be done every 3 hours, taskDescription[1], every 2 hours and taskDescription[2], every 6 hours.

When no task has to be done, I need to display "Free hour".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking an object? That can store the tasks in the `daySchedule`. Then we only need to slice the entries to display the first 3 hours.

```
let daySchedule = {
  "08:00": [1],
  "09:00": [1, 2],
  "10:00": [1, 2, 3],
  "11:00": [],
  "12:00": [],
  "13:00": [],
  "14:00": [],
  "15:00": [],
  "16:00": [],
  "17:00": [],
  "18:00": [],
  "19:00": [],
  "20:00": []
};

let tasks = [1, 2, 3]; 

let taskDescriptions = [
  "Checking vegetables",
  "Baking bread",
  "Cleaning",
  "Free hour"
];

for (const [hour, tasks] of Object.entries(daySchedule).slice(0, 3)) {
  console.log(`${hour} - ${tasks.map(task => taskDescriptions[task - 1]).join(", ")}`);
}
```

Output:

```
08:00 - Checking vegetables
09:00 - Checking vegetables, Baking bread
10:00 - Checking vegetables, Baking bread, Cleaning
```